# Fab icons too small

Tags: css, xml, nativescript

I have an application made with nativescript. I am implementing floating action buttons [fab](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton) but my icons are getting too small inside the fab "circle".

I tried changing the icons size, paddings, and width/height but nothing has worked.

What could be done?

```
<FAB:fab tap="{{addImage}}" icon="res://add" rippleColor="#f56c0a" class="fab-button" />
```

css:

```
.fab-button {
height: 100px;
width: 100px; /* this is required on iOS - Android does not require width so you might need to adjust styles */ 
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
background-color: #f68533;
vertical-align: bottom; 
}
```

[image: FAB]

new screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it's the size of your drawable I believe. Can you provide a link to the drawable image you are using? Did you add the right density to the drawable directories for the android resources?

Comment: I usually use icons from https://icons8.com/icon/set/microphone/all and https://materialdesignicons.com/. I tried changing font-size as above comment and put the icons inside the others drawables folders too. What do you recommend?

Comment: You might be interested in https://material.io/icons/ for icons, you can select the DP size you want and download all the densities you need of the icon to drop in the android drawable directories. As for the font size suggestion, the native android FloatingActionButton descends from android's ImageButton so it doesn't directly allow text (or font usage).

Comment: Ok, I downloaded new icons from your link (I knew that website too) and placed them inside each folder but I think they still look too small. Please take a look at my new image above.

Comment: Don't use `px` but DIPs .. instead `100px` use just `100` (meaning Device INdependent Pixels). In fact, to achieve scalable UI on differently scaled screens , you should never use px in the mobile world but whenever you can the choice should be DPs which is the default option in NativeScript

Comment: @ma.gr - Those look like you downloaded the 24dp images. Try the 36dp from material icons if you want the icon to be larger, or 48 even.

Comment: @BradMartin I did that

Comment: @NickIliev oh yes, I used dpi when I worked with android native dev. If I set 100 the fab gets too big but the icons inside get bigger too. It would be great if the same would happen with 50(dpi). I noticed the smaller the fab, the smaller the icons. It looks like the "padding" increases.